# Bootstrap Select-Picker prevent close

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

Hey Guys I am working with [Bootstrap Select-picker](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/). I want to open the drop list by default and not to close the select-picker on focus out.

**Code**:

```html
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" data-actions-box="true">
  <optgroup label="filter1">
    <option>option1</option>
    <option>option2</option>
    <option>option3</option>
    <option>option4</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="filter2">
    <option>option1</option>
    <option>option2</option>
    <option>option3</option>
    <option>option4</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="filter3">
    <option>option1</option>
    <option>option2</option>
    <option>option3</option>
    <option>option4</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
</script>
```

Is this possible??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add some jQuery to have it auto open, and re-open when anywhere in the document is clicked (causing it normally to lose focus and close)..

```
//auto open
$('[data-id=mySel]').trigger('click');

//stay open
$(document).on("click", function () {
   $('[data-id=mySel]').trigger('click');
});
```

Demo: **http://www.bootply.com/77umTeRI6n**

Comment: Why not just listen for the `focusout` event? Why do this on *any* click?

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by ZimSystem works great, until you need multiple open at the same time, then it fails. The following modification works.

In JavaScript:

```
//initial open
$('[data-id=mySel]').trigger('click');
```

In CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    display: block !important;
    min-height: inherit !important;
    max-height: inherit !important;
}
```